# Reading id3v2 frames with TagLib in Powershell

Tags: powershell, taglib, id3, taglib-sharp

I'm trying to read a file's id3v2 tag information using the [TagLib#](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/) library with Powershell.
Reading the standard tag properties is not a problem (artist, title etc.), but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to read the ID3v2 frames (specifically the COMMENT).

Can anyone provide a simple example as to how to accomplish this?
Documentation on this is scarce it seems.

Comment: Can you give samples of what is working and what is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

This is what I was trying to accomplish:

```
# load the TagLib# assembly into PowerShell
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\taglib-sharp.dll")

$media = [TagLib.MPEG.File]::Create("C:\1812 Overture.mp3")
[TagLib.Id3v2.Tag] $currId3v2 = $media.GetTag([TagLib.TagTypes]::Id3v2)

$commentFrames = $currId3v2.GetFrames("COMM")
...
```

Sorry if I was not descriptive enough.

And thanks for the willingness to help.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me - could you please clarify your question with what isn't working?

```
# load the TagLib# assembly into PowerShell
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\taglib-sharp.dll")

# grab the MP3 file with TagLib
$file = [TagLib.File]::Create("C:\overture.mp3")

# read the COMMENT tag field
$file.Tag.Comment
```

For me at least, this output the following line:

```
Amazon.com Song ID: 123456789
```